# Calculate product price per LineItemfor customize-product plugin not whole cart

Tags: php, shopware

I have a custom problem that I can't solve. In shopware 6 I use the custom products plugin from the Rise plan. https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/extensions/customproducts

The store's default products calculate the cart price according to the rules applied to the entire cart, e.g. $cart->setRulesIds([]), then the processors are launched and recalculate the cart price. I have configured products with an option where:

option 1 has range 1-10, price is 1pcs, and 11-20,price is 2pcs.

In the admin rule creator I set a rule like item quantity -> at least one -> product -> quantity and I think the problem is with "at least one" because when I add an option to the cart, for example 5 pieces and then 12 pieces, the total of the whole item should be 29 (12 * 2 and 5 * 1) and I get 17 (each quantity is converted by 1).

the problem is that shopware calculates the price for the entire cart, not for a specific product, and when it finds and applies the first rule, it ignores the rest {at least one condition}

How can I solve this? I tried using in decorating the collector like this:

```
   if(!$this->ruleMatcher->match(new LineItemScope($optionLineItem, $salesChannelContext))) {
    continue;
}
```

but it doesn't work. I think this is solvable, but I have no idea where I can connect via collector/processor/subscriber/other and what the condition should be